# Bluetooth not working - Atheros AR3011

Tags: networking, drivers, bluetooth, 17.10, atheros

Bluetooth is not working on Ubuntu 17.10.1. I'm new to linux and I don't know what to do. I tried rfkill list and everything is unlocked. sudo lshw shows that it is unclaimed. Is this a driver problem? Driver for this device is in lib/firmware and it's ath3k-1.fw. How to fix this?

```
*-usb:0 UNCLAIMED
                  description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                  product: Asus Integrated Bluetooth module [AR3011]
                  vendor: IMC Networks
                  physical id: 1
                  bus info: usb@1:1.1
                  version: 0.01
                  capabilities: bluetooth usb-1.10
                  configuration: maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
```

I tried 16.04 and it's still not working. dmesg | grep ath

```
[   10.199174] ath9k 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   10.199320] ath: phy0: Set BT/WLAN RX diversity capability
[   10.248017] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x60
[   10.248019] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[   10.248020] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[   10.248021] ath: Regpair used: 0x60
[   12.101571] ath9k 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[   15.587488] ath3k: probe of 1-1.1:1.0 failed with error -110
[   15.587543] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath3k
[   32.641275] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x8348
[   32.641276] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[   32.641277] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[   32.641278] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x3a
[   32.641279] ath: Country alpha2 being used: US
[   32.641280] ath: Regpair used: 0x3a
[   32.641281] ath: regdomain 0x8348 dynamically updated by country IE
```

Comment: Are there any clues in the log? `dmesg | grep ath` Please edit your question to add the result. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 edited

Comment: Please try: `sudo modprobe -r ath9k && sudo modprobe ath9k btcoex_enable=1` If there is any improvement, I will propose an answer.

Comment: Please edit to include results for `lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem just now on Ubuntu 20.04 and was able to solve it by installing linux-modules-extra for my kernel. After a reboot, the bluetooth adapter just started working.

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)
```

You can probably make sure that this is always installed, even in the case of kernel upgrades, by installing linux-generic.

```
sudo apt install linux-generic
```